# Understand Atmega168P Datasheet

Tags: avr, atmega, error

I am in the process of reading through the above mentioned doc from [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8025.pdf).

In page-21, second paragraph in section `8.5 I/O Memory`, line 6 is given as below:

> When using the I/O specific commands IN and OUT, the I/O addresses 0x00 - 0x3F must be used.

However, in page-224, row 1 of table, first column, `Assembly Code Example` has the last line as follows:

```
out TWCR, r16
```

But as per page-21 statment, above instruction is wrong as TWCR has memory address `0xBC` as given in page-396 row 6.

Is there something wrong here, or am I understanding it wrong?

Please help.

**Edit:** [definitions file](http://codeshare.io/vJf5U)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're understanding it wrong.  Yes, TWCR has a *memory* address of 0xBC, but that isn't its IO address.

There are two ways of accessing the port - through IO, and through memory.  In C, when you assign a value to that address it changes the address to be the IO address instead and uses an in or an out instruction rather than load or store instructions.

-- edit --

Looking at the definitions file you have posted, there is this little bit:

```
; ***** I/O REGISTER DEFINITIONS *****************************************
; NOTE:
; Definitions marked "MEMORY MAPPED"are extended I/O ports
; and cannot be used with IN/OUT instructions
....
.equ    TWCR    = 0xbc  ; MEMORY MAPPED
```

I suspect actually that the data sheet is incorrect.  It wouldn't be surprising if that whole section about the TWI were copied verbatim from another data sheet whose TWI interface is IO mapped not memory mapped, such as the ATMega32.  It's not uncommon.

Comment: But am talking about assembly not C.

Comment: Yes, but you're also confusing memory addresses and IO addresses.  The memory address is 0xBC, but the IO address isn't.  I don't know in which file the IO addresses are defined or I'd look it up.

Comment: I am just using C as an example - you write to the *memory* address, and it changes it to the *io* address and uses OUT.

Comment: I have added a link to the definitions file. I am having a tough time understanding it.

Comment: Exactly, when I tried debugging a test code in Atmel Studio it was showing error "out of range"

Comment: The problem they have is that the OUT opcode only has 6 bits for storing the address: `10111PPrrrrrPPPP out P,r` so the maximum address it can use is 2^6-1, or 63 (0x3F). They soon filled that up, so had to come up with other ways of doing it.  Some chips use OUT for some peripherals, some for others, and there's no (or little) common ground between them.